# how to detect 2 intersected (crossed) curves using opencv or python?

Tags: python, opencv

Given an image with 2 intersected curves as shown in the image below, how can I detect and distinguish the 2 curves using opencv or python? (so I need 2 seperate curves)

[image]

Comment: do you know that there will be 2 curves? Do you know what kind of curves they will be (e.g. 1 ellipse and 1 3rd order curve? If yes, you can try a RANSAC based algorithm by randomly picking as many points as needed to create that curves and then checking which other points support that hypthesis. Repeat until you find the curves you wanted and assign all the supporting points to the individual curve.

Comment: as a more general way, look at "gestalt theory", but I don't think there are algorithms for that. Being honest, interpreting, that your image are 2 curves needs domain knowledge and how to split the lines to get the curves might be ambiguous. If you have additional assumptions, e.g. that there may be only one y coordinate per x coordinate for a curve (like in mathematics), the problem gets easier. Maybe you can just cluster positions per y coordinate.

Comment: You could try template matching with an X-shaped small image and find the location of the brightest spot in the result.

Comment: @Micka many thanks! I still need some time to understand code in your solution. I feel that points me to the right direction. In real-case senario, the curves are effectively the tails of sperms under microscope. And they could tangle with each other in any form, any number, and I was wondering if there is a way to separate each of them. I could upload sample image should you be interested.

Comment: @fmw42 in real-case senario, the curves are effectively tails of sperms tangling with each other in any form, by any number. They are not necessarily in the form of an "x".

Comment: this domain will probably have a lot of different challenges. My solution is quite optimized for scanning each individual columns, which will probably not work in a more chaotic scenario with additional noise etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could scan each column and identify clusters there from connected parts.

pseudo algorithm:

```
list of curves
for each column
    if a pixel region is black, surrounded by white
        add it to the list of curves for which it continues the curve best
```

the most tricky part is, how to define how an already given curve is continued best. If you just choose the distance to the closest point of the curve, you'll get problems in the junction.
Creating a line from the previous to last point of a curve to the new point and measuring the distance to the last point of the curve worked quite well. However, because of measuring very small distances (maybe with rounding problems etc.), I didn't iterate over all columns, but only every 5th column.

[image]

C++ code here:

```
double distance_to_Line(cv::Point line_start, cv::Point line_end, cv::Point point)
{
    double normalLength = _hypot(line_end.x - line_start.x, line_end.y - line_start.y);
    double distance = (double)((point.x - line_start.x) * (line_end.y - line_start.y) - (point.y - line_start.y) * (line_end.x - line_start.x)) / normalLength;
    return abs(distance);
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat in = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/splitCurves.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    std::vector<std::vector <cv::Point2f> > clusters;
    float maxDist = 10.0f; //heuristic

    // looping like this is quite expensive, but we need to scan column-wise
    // will be cheaper to first transpose the image and then scan row-wise!!
    for (int x = 0; x < in.cols; x+=5)
    {
        bool active = false;
        cv::Point2f cCluster;
        int cClusterSupportSize = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < in.rows; ++y)
        {
            cv::Point2f cPoint = cv::Point2f(x, y);
            bool cActive = in.at<unsigned char>(y,x) == 0; // is the pixel black?
            if (cActive)
            {
                cCluster += cPoint;
                cClusterSupportSize += 1;
                active = cActive;
            }

            if (active && !cActive)
            {
                // creating cluster:
                cv::Point2f finishedCluster = 1.0f / cClusterSupportSize * cCluster;

                cCluster = cv::Point2f();
                cClusterSupportSize = 0;
                active = false;

                // adding cluster to list
                int bestCluster = -1;
                float bestDist = FLT_MAX;
                for (int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); ++i)
                {
                    float distToClusters = FLT_MAX;

                    // compute dist from apprximating a line through the last two points of the curve
                    // special case: no 2 points yet:
                    if (clusters[i].size() == 1)
                    {
                        float cDist = cv::norm(finishedCluster - clusters[i].back());
                        if (cDist < distToClusters) distToClusters = cDist;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // test continuity by testing whether adding the new point would make the last point still be placed well on the curve
                        cv::Point2f lineA = clusters[i][clusters[i].size() - 1];
                        cv::Point2f lineB = clusters[i][clusters[i].size() - 2];
                        //cv::Point2f lineB = finishedCluster;
                        // get dist from the current point to that line:

                        float cDist =  distance_to_Line(lineA, lineB, finishedCluster);
                        if (cDist < distToClusters) distToClusters = cDist;
                    }



                    /*
                    for (int j = 0; j < clusters[i].size(); ++j)
                    {
                        // get dist to the curve
                        cv::Point2f lineA = 
                        //float cDist = cv::norm(finishedCluster - clusters[i][j]);
                        if (cDist < distToClusters) distToClusters = cDist;
                    }
                    */

                    if (distToClusters < maxDist)
                    {
                        if (distToClusters < bestDist)
                        {
                            bestDist = distToClusters;
                            bestCluster = i;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (bestCluster < 0)
                {
                    std::vector<cv::Point2f> newCluster;
                    newCluster.push_back(finishedCluster);
                    clusters.push_back(newCluster);
                }
                else
                {
                    clusters[bestCluster].push_back(finishedCluster);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    cv::Mat out;
    cv::cvtColor(in, out, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    for (int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(i*rand() % 255, (i+2)*rand() % 255, (i+1) * 100);
        if (i == 0) color = cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0);
        if (i == 1) color = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255);
        for (int j = 1; j < clusters[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            cv::line(out, clusters[i][j - 1], clusters[i][j], color, 2);
        }
    }
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Input/splitCurves_out.png", out);
    cv::imshow("out", out);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to elaborate on your sample to see if it answers my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505748/separate-crossings-segments-in-binarised-image  This is what I'm getting, do you have any idea what is going wrong? https://i.imgur.com/Eb5zd9z.png

Comment: my code assumes 2 coarsely horizontal  line directions. You have more cluster and some more vertical lines. First thing you should do is splitting the image into one individual image for each contour (result are 4 images) and process the lines for each of them. Then you'll have to estimate the number of lines in each of the images (3 in your case) and think about whether the clustering approach can still work. You could think about a medial axis approach instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by medial axis approach? I've you have any literature to recommend, I'll be happy to study it.

Comment: should be similar to your skeleton approach. If you can find the skeleton and the external points (the "finger-tips") of each curve, my clustering approach could probably be adapted to your scenario.